# Changing the size of the array in an OpenCL kernel

Tags: opencl

I hope someone can help me with this.

I need to pass a long array representing a matrix to an opencl kernel using something like this:

```
memObjects[2] = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                               sizeof(double) * dets_numel, dets, NULL);
```

Inside the kernel I would like to remove some rows of the matrix depending on some condition and then read it back to the host using something like:

```
errNum = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[2], CL_TRUE, 0,
                             dims1[0] * dims1[1] * sizeof(double), dets,
                             0, NULL, NULL);
```

Is there a way to let the host part of the program know the exact size of the array (matrix) without executing another kernel that will compute the size and read the result from the buffer back to the host?

Comment: Even if you find a working solution, you're going to be better off not doing it in the kernel.  This is a much better task for a linear CPU than a parallel GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a workaround specifically for your problem, but in general - No. You either find out new size implicitly, either read back explicit value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't change the size of the stored device memory, but you can write on just part of it and read that part back to the host:

- For the first part, you should make a bit different mapping on your
  kernel, according to what you want.
- Try using the `clEnqueueReadBufferRect()` function for the second
  part.